# get the value of a json

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this:

```
alert = Alert(title=a,
          tlp=3,
          tags=tags,
          description='N/A',
          type='external',
          source='instance1',
          sourceRef=sourceRef,
          artifacts=artifacts)
```

And I want to know how to get the value of 'title', I tried to do this:

```
print(alert['title'])
```

but doesnt work:

> TypeError: 'Alert' object is not subscriptable

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert` is a Python object. You should use the dot notation ( **`alert.title`** ) instead of `alert['title']`.

With that said, if for some reason you are actually interested in doing `alert['title']` you can implement `__getitem__` in `Alert`:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    return getattr(self, item)
```

This is the most basic implementation possible. You may want to take care of cases where `item` doesn't exist (currently the exception will propagate to the calling code)

```
class Foo:
    x = 1

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self, item)


f = Foo()
print(f['x'])
# 1
print(f['y']
# AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'y'
```

One way to handle missing attributes would be to use the 3<sup>rd</sup> argument of `getattr` which is the default value in case the searched attribute doesn't exist:

```
class Foo:
    x = 1

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self, item, None)


f = Foo()
print(f['y'])
# None
```